# The Japanese term for "synonym discussion"?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, word-requests

In English, when I want to know the subtle differences in meaning between similar words I consult a thesaurus's synonym discussion. To give an example of this, see halfway down [Merriam-Webster's thesaurus page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ponder) for the word "ponder". Several English thesauruses have them, but not all thesauruses do.

Is there a term for this which Japanese thesauruses conventionally use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar section in [a Japanese thesaurus](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/682/meaning/m0u/%E5%BA%A7%E3%82%8B/) names itself **使い分け**—"usage differentiation" or "using accordingly", and I think this is a pretty stable choice of word. It however does not contain the word "synonym", which, in the case you want specify, could be added like 類語の使い分け.